# Set minimum duration for Sprite Kit action

Tags: sprite-kit, duration, skaction

I have implemented the following method in my Sprite Kit Game:

```
-(void) sprayWater{  
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:self.runWasserFrames timePerFrame:0.05 resize:YES restore:YES]] withKey:@"water"];    
}
```

What ist the most elegant way to set the minimum time of this action to 1,5 seconds?
I tried several ways, but they did not work out for me so far.

Comment: what do you mean by minimum time? An action runs either indefinitely (via repeatforever), or for a specific duration

Comment: I call this method above in the touchesBegan-Method. As long as the screen is pressed, the main character sprays water. Everything works out fine, but when you press the screen with a high frequency, the frame rate drops to 30fps. I would like to prevent that by setting a minimum time for this action, in which the method is called and touches in the meantime are useless, so they don't affect the framerate. An specific duration does not fit my needs, cause the water should be sprayed as long as the screen ist pressed. Can't think of any possibilty to fix that issue...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly, you should try something like this :

```
-(void) sprayWater
{  

        if ([self actionForKey:@"water"] == nil)
        {
             [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:self.runWasserFrames timePerFrame:0.05 resize:YES restore:YES]] withKey:@"water"];   
        } 
}
```

The logic is that if the water is already running, don't create another action.